# Where to configure unattended-upgrades

Tags: apt, configuration, unattended-upgrades

Regarding configuration of Unattended-Upgrades:

1. Which are the appropriate files for configuring each option of Unattended-Upgrades?

   I have seen three files mentioned, see below.
   I am not certain others could also be used.
2. Can any of the files above be used for any of the options, or there is a restriction on this? (There is some overlap, for sure, see below).
3. Which has precedence for repeated options?

PS: These are actually different questions, but intimately related, so it would be possibly less convenient to separate them into different posts.

What I see in my 18.04LTS:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades 
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic 
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
(long output)
```

PS2:
As for how to configure or disable, these are related

[Limiting the time Unattended-Upgrade keeps the lock on `/var/lib/dpkg/`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226837/limiting-the-time-unattended-upgrade-keeps-the-lock-on-var-lib-dpkg)

[Ubuntu 16.04: Unattended-upgrades runs at random times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824718/ubuntu-16-04-unattended-upgrades-runs-at-random-times)

[Unattended-upgrades running for hours](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226779/unattended-upgrades-running-for-hours)

[Disable automatic updates ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167314/disable-automatic-updates-ubuntu-18-04)

[disable updates from command line in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059971/disable-updates-from-command-line-in-ubuntu-16-04)

[Disable Software Updater Notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117139/disable-software-updater-notification)

[How to Enable/Disable Unattended Upgrades in Ubuntu 16.04](https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/enable-disable-unattended-upgrades-ubuntu-16-04/)

[Terminate and disable/remove unattended upgrade before command returns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463498/terminate-and-disable-remove-unattended-upgrade-before-command-returns)

Comment: Seems clear to me what each does, and dpkg will happily tell you which packages provide each file. Files are processed in numeric order - later files overrule earlier. You can place any option anywhere you wish. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @user535733 - I have specific questions, and your helped better ordering them, please see edit.
Your answer (in a comment) was concise. If I understand correctly, this is what you mean, please comment:
1) You didn't specify all configuration files associated with Unattended-Upgrade.
2) Yes. In fact, strictly speaking any file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` could contain any configuration option for unattended-upgrade, and they would be equally processed. The decision on where to place them helps organization, and accounting for the precedence.
3) Files are processed in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

As for the precedence of the configurations files, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/254137/21005)

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic is related to *update-notifier-common* package.
Same setting variables that are set in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades will override those settings. You can setup the `20auto-upgrades` file by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`. If you use the GUI way i.e. "Software & Updates" dialog i.e. `/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk` (its *Updates* tab), it will change both files. As for scheduling unattended-upgrades, I suppose it goes the same way as with Debian; see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342663/111181) question.

You should not modify /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades. Instead, use files starting with e.g. "51" to override some of the settings:

> To override the configuration it is recommended to create an other APT
> configuration file fragment which overrides the shipped default value
> because updates to to shipped configuration file may conflict with the
> local changes blocking updating unattended-upgrades itself. The new
> file should sort later than 50unattended-upgrades to be parsed later
> than the one shipping the default values, it can be e.g.
> 52unattended-upgrades-local.

Reference: https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/README.md